# Google Sheet Chart - Can't Display Series

Tags: google-sheets

I have a very simple data set of three columns showing content submissions by day. I want a simple Google Sheets line chart showing volume of each content submission by day. For some reason I can't get the content type to show as the series and not matter what I do it won't show as an option. It shows as an option for the x-axis, but not the series. I feel like I'm missing something very simple here.

[image]

Comment: When you say `showing volume of each content submission by day`  what are you referring to? based on what, are you grouping your data?
 Also, in the example picture, the 3 columns have the same data so the line chart seems to display the right information. Could you provide an example of your expected result? If you could share a sheet with sample data that would be really helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

In cell E1, put this formula:

```
=QUERY(A:C,"select A,SUM(B) where A is not null group by A pivot C",1)
```

then select that data and Insert>Chart

the graph expects pivoted data.